# Selenium WebDriver : Verify whether a check-box is selected or NOT using JavaScript Executor

Tags: javascript, html, selenium

I have a scenario in Webdriver which deals with checking whether group of check-boxes present is selected or not. I am using a locator something like the following to get the number of check-box(s) selected:

```
List<WebElement> listOfColumnsSelected = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='<ID_of_Div_under_which_check_boxes_are_placed>']//input[@type='checkbox'][@checked='checked']");
System.out.println(listOfColumnsSelected.size());
```

This returns me correct count of selected check-box for Firefox and IE9. But when trying in IE7, it returns **null** as in IE7, there is NO **checked attribute** present for check-boxes. How to get the same list in IE7? Please help if anyone aware about this.

**Note:** 
I can think of one alternative by iterating through each and every check-box and check whether selected or not using **isSelected()** method. But don't want to use it as it consumes a lot of time. Rather using driver.findElements() is a quick process when we have to check from a group of 100 or more odd check-boxes.

Thanks,
Sitam Jana 
Software QA Engineer 
[Mindfire Solutions](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used java script to do something similar. Here is my code:

```
String selectedCB = "";
String jsScript = "var selchbox = [];"
    +"var inpfields = document.getElementsByName('city[]');"
    +"var nr_inpfields = inpfields.length;"
    +"for(var i=0; i<nr_inpfields; i++) {"
    +"    if(inpfields[i].type == 'checkbox' && inpfields[i].checked == true) selchbox.push(inpfields[i].value);"
    +"  }"
    +"var selected;"
    +"selected = selchbox.join('#') + \"#\";"
    +"return selected;";
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
selectedCB = (String) executor.executeScript(jsScript);
String[] selectedB = selectedCB.split("#");
```

You may alter it, for your check box element in line *document.getElementsByName('city[]');*.

Comment: Happy to have been of help :)